# npm command return err_require_esm

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I want to check if i have npm installed in my PC and I cant run `npm --help` in my PC

I typed `npm --help` and got this message:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFCQb.png)

```
D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\wide-align\node_modules\string-width\index.js:2
var stripAnsi = require('strip-ansi');
                ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js from D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\wide-align\node_modules\string-width\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js in D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\wide-align\node_modules\string-width\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\wide-align\node_modules\string-width\index.js:2:17) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```